# using helper return values as parameter values to another helper, or subexpressions

Tags: dust.js

ahoy all,

looking if it is possible to use the return value of one helper as a parameter to another directly in dust.js ([linkedin's](https://github.com/linkedin) or [original flavor](https://github.com/akdubya/dustjs)) e.g.

```
you have {@math key="{@size key=list/}" method="add" operand="4"/} new messages
```

assuming that `@size` will return some scalar value like `3` if list is:

```
{
  "list": ["msg1", "msg2", "msg3"]
}
```

so far it seems to not be possible, getting an `SyntaxError: Expected buffer, comment, end of input, partial, raw, reference, section or special but "{" found. At line : 1, column : 10` error.

i assume that i can create/use a helper that could set a value in the context from the return value of the first `size` helper and then reuse that value (in essence a temporary variable) in the second `math` helper.  for example, this [provide helper](https://github.com/rragan/dust-motes/tree/master/src/helpers/data/provide) seems to do just that:

```
{@provide}
  {@math key=len method="add" operand="4"/}
{:len}
  {@size key=list/}
{/provide}
```

however, i was hoping to avoid these extra steps with something like subexpressions supported Handlebars: see section on Subexpressions [on this page](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) and [this pull request which added the feature](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/690).  subexpressions allow the one helper to be embedded as a parameter value of the second helper, as i have illustrated in my first example.

perhaps i am missing a more *dust-way* to handle this?  thus any pointers appreciated.

thanks/peace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Dust-like" way to handle this is to write a context function that does exactly what you intend, thus removing all logic from the template.

By nesting helpers, you are, in Dust's view, adding too much logic to a template. (This is not the only correct view, but it is Dust's view.)

This also gives you the ability to take advantage of Dust's super-handy block syntax, which gives you a falsy `else` block for free, and lets you create extra blocks to extract any remaining logic from the template.

So you should solve this problem with a template like:

```
You have {#numMessages}{.} messages!{:else}no messages at all.{/numMessages}
```

And a context function:

```
{
   "list": ["msg1", "msg2", "msg3"],
   "numMessages": function(chunk, context) {
       // return this.list.length + 4; // this works if list is in the same context
       return context.get("list").length + 4; // safer, finds list by walking the context tree
   }
}
```

So now, none of these "logic" items are in the template:

- The name of the variable that contains my messages
- The fact that I should add to this number to get the true number
- The special number 4

Comment: thanks for the very detailed and informative answer. IMHO the nesting of helpers just seems like a nice shortcut w/o adding "too much" logic. however, i am new to the logic-less Mustache world and i really like the intention/philosophy so trying to digest this line of thinking. thanks again for your time.